# Separate variables for each thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a problem with values being passed from threads to threads. I just want that every thread once started has the variable with the thread-only values. For example, if I have a `requests.session`, I don't want that the session for Thread 1 and 2 are the same.

```
import requests
import threading

def functionName():
   s=requests.session()
   r=s.get("") #get a random site
   #do some things

if __name__== "__main__":
    t=threading.Thread(target=functionName)
    tt=threading.Thread(target=functionName)
    t.start()
    tt.start()
```

If I add other actions instead of `#do some things` and save the whole results in a file, it looks like the two threads got merged and worked in an unique session, even if I want the 2 sessions being separate for each Thread.

Comment: I think you are talking about data race right?, if it is you can create a lock function to prevent this data race condition. Ex:
```def locking_increment():
    with db.get_lock():
        return increment()
```

Comment: You could also think about using processes instead of threads because processes don't share memory

Comment: The variables, `r` and `s`, are _local_ variables. They aren't shared between threads.  So if there's any problem here, it's in the implementation of `requests.session()` or in the implementation of `s.get()`. What do those functions look like?

Comment: I think @SolomonSlow's point about `r` and `s` already being local variables is correct, but doubt the "problem" is because of the way `session` and `get` are implemented — and instead suspect it's due to whatever `#do something things` is (and/or code in the main thread also not shown). It's impossible to tell for sure without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description of the problem and the fact that `r` and `s` *are* already local to each thread (as @Solomon Slow pointed-out in a comment), I suspect the problem is with how you're obtaining the results from each thread.

Since you haven't provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I made up something to show one way that can be done. In it, the results of each thread are stored in a shared global dictionary named `merged`. As you can see from the output, the two threads did not interfere with one another.

```
from ast import literal_eval
import requests
import threading
from random import randint


def functionName(thread_name, shared, lock):
    s = requests.Session()
    sessioncookie = str(randint(100000000, 123456789))
    s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/' + sessioncookie)
    r = s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies')
    r_as_dict = literal_eval(r.text)

    print('r_as_dict:', r_as_dict)

    # Store result in shared dictionary.
    with lock:
        shared[thread_name] = r_as_dict['cookies']['sessioncookie']


if __name__ == '__main__':

    merged = {}
    mlock = threading.Lock()  # Control concurrent access to "merged" dict.

    t=threading.Thread(target=functionName, args=('thread1', merged, mlock))
    tt=threading.Thread(target=functionName, args=('thread2', merged, mlock))
    t.start()
    tt.start()
    t.join()
    tt.join()

    print(merged)
```

Sample output:

```
r_as_dict: {'cookies': {'sessioncookie': '111147840'}}
r_as_dict: {'cookies': {'sessioncookie': '119511820'}}
{'thread1': '111147840', 'thread2': '119511820'}
```